# flutter Scrollcontroller not scrolling all members of a stack

Tags: riverpod, scrollcontroller, flutter-sliverappbar

I am using Riverpod for state management in flutter. The fabButton included in a stack that should scroll with other elements in a sliverAppBar does not scroll. Other elements scroll but the FAB. Below are images of the simulation and the code. Not sure why and what I am doing wrong. Maybe a third eye and wiser mind can assist. Thanks.

[image: App state]
[image: State after scrolling. FAB is left behind]

[image: code snippet 1]

[image: Code snippet 2]
[image: code snippet 3]
[image: code snippet 4]
[image: code snippet 5]